# i want to compare a time input from user to make sure its in the right format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that accepts time input from the user in am/pm format. I want to make sure if the user enters something else, it would bring out an error and not just crash the program.
what I am saying is this, the user must enter the time in HH:MM am/pm format. e.g "2:00 pm" or "11:00 am" and any other thing else calls for an error.

The best I could do is

```
print("Make all inputs using the format 'hh:mm am/pm' e.g 10:00 am ... and add 0 before single numbers  e.g 3 ==> 03" )
while True:
   start = input("At what is the start time?: ")
   end = input("At what is the end time?: ")
   if len(start) != 8:
      print("error! wrong value/format entered as the start time")
   elif len(end) != 8:
      print("error! wrong value/format entered as the end time")
   else:
      break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two ways of doing it, I personally prefer the **Date Conversion Method**.

### Date Conversion Method

I would check if I can convert them to a date Python object.  I used `%H:%M %p`, it goes hour:minute am/pm (as your prompt specifies).

```
import time
print("Make all inputs using the format 'hh:mm am/pm' e.g 10:00 am ... and add 0 before single numbers  e.g 3 ==> 03" )
while True:
  start = input("At what is the start time?: ")
  end = input("At what is the end time?: ")

  try:
      time.strptime(start,'%H:%M %p')
      time.strptime(end,'%H:%M %p')
      print("Good Strings")
  except:
      print("Bad Strings")
```

### Regex Method

I'd use the following regex:

```
r"^(?:1?[012]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]\s*(?:am|pm)$"i
```

Here's a Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/Z1YMap/2

Comment: Thank you soooooooooo much!!